# Take a list and make it into strings

Tags: python, random, cpu-word

Basically I'm trying to make a random word generator but I want to be able to copy and paste the words into python and then have it change each word into a string so I can randomly choose.

The code I'm going to use is similar to this:

```
import random
a = ["Cat", "DOG", "MOM"]
print(random.choice(a))
```

I'm a python newbie, so if there is an easier way to make a random word generator let me know. Its going to have two generators, one for verbs and one for nouns.

Answer (score 0):

Words are strings. This code looks good to me. But if you're looking for efficiency, try this :

---

`verbs.txt`

```
run play skip jump
```

---

`nouns.txt`

```
cat book rope rock
```

---

`script.py`

```
verbs = open('verbs.txt').read().split(' ')
verb = random.choice(verbs)

nouns = open('nouns.txt').read().split(' ')
noun = random.choice(nouns)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

May you can read a file to read the words and deal with them like this:

passage:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

read and split word into a list and randomly print :

```
import re
import random

fd = open('data.txt')
lines = [i.strip() for i in fd]

words = []
for line in lines:
  for word in ''.join(re.split('[,;.!]', line)).split(' '):
    words.append(word)

# pick up 5 words
for i in range(5):
  print random.choice(words)
```

But I don't know how you get verbs or nouns... may helps

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to save a list of plain-text words into a text file and then programatically read the file into python.

Take this example text file (saved as "words.txt" in the same directory as your python program):

```
cat dog cow man cheese
```

You would use the following code to read it into python and store it as a list of strings

```
infile = open("words.txt", 'r') #open the file for reading
a = infile.read().strip().split(" ") #read in the file and divide into words by splitting on spaces
print random.choice(a) #print a random word from the file
infile.close() #close the file
```

Comment: If you could accept the answer you use, that would be great.